# Upload file : change extensions of files

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm actually making upload for any files. First, i tried to upload picture files (.png, .jpg, ...) and it's worked! But when I tried to upload video files like .ogv, .mov, .mp4, the file is uploaded but the extension of the file is changed .ogx for .ogv and .mp4 and .qt for .mov. I don't know where is the error because the code is coming from Symfony website.

Here's my code:

```
 /**
 * @Assert\File(maxSize="6000000")
 */
public $file;

public function getWebPath()
{
    return null === $this->path ? null : $this->getUploadDir().'/'.$this->path;
}

protected function getUploadRootDir()
{
    // le chemin absolu du répertoire où les documents uploadés doivent être sauvegardés
   return __DIR__.'/../../../../web/'.$this->getUploadDir();
}

protected function getUploadDir()
{
    // on se débarrasse de « __DIR__ » afin de ne pas avoir de problème lorsqu'on affiche
    // le document/image dans la vue.
    return 'uploads/documents';
}

// propriété utilisé temporairement pour la suppression
private $filenameForRemove;

/**
 * @ORM\PrePersist()
 * @ORM\PreUpdate()
 */
public function preUpload()
{
    if (null !== $this->file) {
        $this->path = $this->file->guessExtension();
    }
}

/**
 * @ORM\PostPersist()
 * @ORM\PostUpdate()
 */
public function upload()
{
    if (null === $this->file) {
        return;
    }

    // vous devez lancer une exception ici si le fichier ne peut pas
    // être déplacé afin que l'entité ne soit pas persistée dans la
    // base de données comme le fait la méthode move() de UploadedFile
    $this->file->move($this->getUploadRootDir(), $this->id.'.'.$this->file->guessExtension());

    unset($this->file);
}

/**
 * @ORM\PreRemove()
 */
public function storeFilenameForRemove()
{
    $this->filenameForRemove = $this->getAbsolutePath();
}

/**
 * @ORM\PostRemove()
 */
public function removeUpload()
{
    if ($this->filenameForRemove) {
        unlink($this->filenameForRemove);
    }
}

public function getAbsolutePath()
{
    return null === $this->path ? null : $this->getUploadRootDir().'/'.$this->id.'.'.$this->path;
}
```

Thanks in advance !

PokeR

Comment: Have you tried replacing `guessExtension()` with `getExtension()` ?

Comment: getExtension() giving files with .tmp extension.

Comment: Ah, perhaps you could extract the extension from `getClientOriginalName()`

Comment: @PokeRwOw you should also check server's mime type list

Comment: getClientOriginalName() works fine thanks for your help ! :)